# How can I fix duo <td> breaking my table (Email template)

Tags: html, css, email, html-table, html-email

I have two imgs I am trying to pad out without their borders getting padded out as well. To achieve this, I have both of the imgs in two separate 'tds' both in the same 'tr'.

Edit for formatting clarity: both 'tds' were assigned the same class, but I don't believe that is the issue.

Class attributes for td:

```
table.container td.logo { 
    border-collapse:collapse; 
    width: 50%; 
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:center; 
    align:left; 
    padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Class attributes for img class:

```
.circle-icons { 
    max-width: 100px;
    /*Opera, IE9,Safari, Android 2.1+ clients*/
    border-radius:50%; 
    /* Safari 3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android 1.6- */
    -webkit-border-radius:50%;
    /* Firefox 1-3.6 */
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid #ECECEC;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Code in action:

```
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="container" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="border-spacing: 0;font-family: Lato, Arial, sans-serif;color: #434343;">
    <tr>
        <td class="logo" style="border-collapse:collapse; text-align:center; color:#fff;">
            <img src="http://static.cdn~.png" class="circle-icons" />
        </td>
        <td class="logo" style="border-collapse:collapse; text-align: left; color: #fff;">
            <img src="http://static.cdn~.png" class="circle-icons" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the current result: by doing a forced width:50% (I know, not a huge fan of it either) I am able to "force" the first td over to the left, but the second td is still breaking the table.

Here's a screengrab: [Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Az51P9xCkjQ0NLbkdXUi1TVWc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: How is the TD "breaking the table"? Can you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve? You say "I have both imgs in two separate both in the same and part of the same class." Can you fix this sentence so it reads correctly?

Comment: @GeoffPhillips ultimately, I am trying to have both IMGs padded without having padding between the image and the circular borders. 
I thought I could achieve this by placing both IMGs in two separate tds and  specifying the Padding there. However, when I place both the tds in a <tr>, the tds break the template (see the link in OP)

Comment: @GeoffPhillips if you haven't already, check out the linked image in the OP as well-- I edited as well to clarify

Comment: hello, first of all if this goes for emails border radius wont work in most platforms like outlooks, secondly  always remmeber to set with and height to img elements when you design email in different platforms gmail, yahoo, lotus, outlook, ios, andoid,aol looks different. I think best way is to do for example you set on tds 50% so for example if its responsive you get on desktop 600px full then count yourself circle max 300px each (full) so img 290px + 5px border each side. And then when you will do media queries you can use classes because reponsive work only for andoid and ios in emails

Comment: I will dont understand what you are trying to accomplish with this. Do you just want two images in 50% boxes side-by-side with some padding inbetween?